# Class method: 'self' not being read

Tags: python

For some reason, in a method I make, I put self as the first parameter, but it doesn't read it. When I try to run the method, it says it needs the 'self' positional argument.

```
class Monster():
    name = "Snake"
    health = 100

    def decreaseHealth(self):
        if health <= 0:
            print('Dead')
        health -= 4

Monster.decreaseHealth()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're calling `decreaseHealth()` on the class itself, whereas you should be calling it on an *instance* of the class:

```
m = Monster()
m.decreaseHealth()
```

This will automatically bind `self` to `m`.

P.S. To refer to `health` inside the method, use `self.health`.

Here is a version that fixes a couple of other (mainly stylistic) issues:

```
class Monster(object):

  def __init__(self):
     self.name = "Snake"
     self.health = 100

  def decreaseHealth(self):
     if self.health <= 0:
        print('Dead')
     else:
        self.health -= 4

m = Monster()
m.decreaseHealth()
```

Comment: I'll accept this one because it has the code, and is the simpler answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a *class method*, better make it one:

```
@classmethod
def decreaseHealth(cls):
    ...
```

Then you can call `Monster.decreaseHealth`, and you can access the class variables with `cls.` (e.g. `cls.health`). But, then, you are operating on "global" state associated with the class itself.

You probably want to make an *instance* of your monster instead:

```
class Monster:
    ''' Base class for monsters '''

class Snake(Monster):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Snake"
        self.health = 100
    def decreaseHealth(self):
        self.health -= 4
        if self.health <= 0:
            print("dead")

mysnake = Snake()
mysnake.decreaseHealth()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the way you are calling *decreaseHealth()* there is no *self* argument. *self* refers to the object on which a method was called. Here you have no object, you are trying to call the method on the class name.

You need to create a Monster object, *then* call your method:

```
monster = Monster();
monster.decreaseHealth()
```